# Private DB Link in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, dblink

I want to create one private DB link. I have searched Oracle website, it was clear as mud. It will be helpful if anyone can explain the syntax to create private db link Also the syntactic difference between private db link and public DB link.

And lastly, how can I verify that the created DB Link is private or public ?

Comment: The [Oracle documentation for `CREATE DATABASE LINK` syntax is here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm) - don't use the `PUBLIC` keyword and it will not be public (a.k.a. it will be private).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MT0 pointed out, the [SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-DATABASE-LINK.html) explains that the lack of the keyword `PUBLIC` makes the database link private.

Below is an example of creating a public and private database link:

```
--Create public and private database links.
create public database link public_link
connect to fake_user identified by fake_password using 'fake tns entry';

create database link private_link
connect to fake_user identified by fake_password using 'fake tns entry';
```

Here is how to query the data dictionary to find if the links are public or private.  Public links are be owned by `PUBLIC`, private links are owned by a real user.

```
--View the database links in the data dictionary.
--(The link name may be slightly different than what you asked for because of the DB_DOMAIN.)
select owner, db_link
from all_db_links
where db_link like '%LINK%'
order by 1,2;

OWNER     DB_LINK
-------   ----------------------------
JHELLER   PRIVATE_LINK.COYOTE.ACME.COM
PUBLIC    PUBLIC_LINK.COYOTE.ACME.COM
```